# Setting SOAP Version with node-soap.

Tags: node.js, soap

I'm using this npm-module: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap

The webservice I want to consume is only using SOAP 1.2 and returns a server error on using any other SOAP version.

Has someone experienced the same problem and knows how to set the SOAP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go into soap\lib\client.js to the line 186 and modify the envelope syntaxis so it is compliant with soap 1.2:

```
 //modify this with the envelope used by soap1.2:
xml = "<soap:Envelope " +
    "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " +
    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
    'xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"' +
    "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
    encoding +
    this.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope + '>' +
    //until here
    ((self.soapHeaders || self.security) ?
      (
        "<soap:Header>" +
        (self.soapHeaders ? self.soapHeaders.join("\n") : "") +
        (self.security ? self.security.toXML() : "") +
        "</soap:Header>"
      )
      :
        ''
      ) +
    "<soap:Body" +
    (self.bodyAttributes ? self.bodyAttributes.join(' ') : '') +
    ">" +
    message +
    "</soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 11):

With latest version of https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap, there is option to set SOAP 1.2 header

```
var options = {
    forceSoap12Headers: true
};
soap.createClient(url,options, function (err, client) {
    //Your soap call here
});
```

IMO, I dont think we should modify the lib, not good for upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue changing as NicolasZ said, my current soap/lib/client.js is:

line 187:

```
 xml = "<soap:Envelope " +
//"xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " +
"xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" " +
"xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
encoding +
this.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope + '>' +
((self.soapHeaders || self.security) ?
  (
    "<soap:Header>" +
    (self.soapHeaders ? self.soapHeaders.join("\n") : "") +
    (self.security ? self.security.toXML() : "") +
    "</soap:Header>"
  )
  :
    ''
  ) +
"<soap:Body" +
(self.bodyAttributes ? self.bodyAttributes.join(' ') : '') +
">" +
message +
"</soap:Body>" +
"</soap:Envelope>";
```